# change order of variables for plots in effects package- prob easy but can't figure it out

Tags: r

I made a plot using the effects package in R, which I think draws on lattice for plotting, but can't figure out how to change the order of the variables. Here is the plot:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
c <- glm(abundance ~ month*site*habitat+sg_biomass+mac_biomass, 
         data=epifauna, family=poisson)
e <- effect(c("month","site","habitat"), c)
plot(e)
```

What I want is for the habitat to be on the x axis, and for there to be 3 columns and two rows, the top row month "J" and the bottom row month "A", and the 3 sites to be 3 seperate plots, hence the 3 columns.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for changing the x-variable:
plot(e,"habitat"), or
plot(e,x.var="habitat")